# How to sort HTML content based on class present on divs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML page which gets some contents from cloud and other content is displayed statically. Each content Item goes into a div which will have a class to mark the category of content item.

What I want is to display the page such that all the items(from both cloud as well as static) appear in a sequence ordered by category.

I can sort the data coming from cloud using linq. How to sort the html page using the class present on each div?

Thanks

Comment: Clarification: do you actually need to sort the HTML? It sounds like you might have the ability to sort the data before it's turned into HTML. Also, an example of what you have tried so far would be helpful please.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst   The cshtml page's Model contains the sorted items from cloud. But the page also has static html. One way I tried is to write separate code for each category. i.e before static content for a category; I  use a for loop to insert the data from cloud in that category. This works;  but is it overkill?

Comment: I guess that instead of sorting the HTML; there is also the option of moving div elements around so that divs of a category are grouped together

Comment: I would argue that any amount of JS needed to avoid parsing HTML is worth it. Parsing HTML is slow, and reordering the DOM is even slower.